# Marine Traffic Map - Latitude/Longitude Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gps, latitude-longitude

I have created a map from  my webpage showing ais-ships in a certain location:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  width='40%';          //the width of the embedded map in pixels or percentage
  height=430;           //the height of the embedded map in pixels or percentage
  border=1;            //the width of border around the map. Zero means no border
  notation=false;      //true or false to display or not the vessel icons and 
                       //options at the left
  shownames=false;     //true or false to dispaly ship names on the map
  latitude=59.01;      //the latitude of the center of the map in decimal degrees
  longitude=5.78;      //the longitude of the center of the map in decimal degrees
  zoom=10;             //the zoom level of the map. Use values between 2 and 17
  maptype=3;                                                    
  trackvessel=0;       //the MMSI of the vessel to track, if within the range 
  fleet='';            //the registered email address of a user-defined fleet 
  remember=false;     
  scale=2;

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.marinetraffic.com/ais/embed.js">
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Instead of punching in the longitude and latitude manually in the code, I wish to put the GPS position retrieved from for example an iPhone in these fields. I've tried several solutions, but I don't seem to get it right. Does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Please always declare a variable with `var a='foo'`

Comment: What have you tried? How do you get the GPS coordinates? You will need to somehow inject those coordinates into a file served to the browser, for instance, can you use PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML5 Geolocation to get Lat,Long, but that will ask user for permission and your code will fail if user reject. Here's how

```
if (navigator.geolocation) 
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
    {  
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude; 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Note that this is ansync so your code have to start after `getCurrentPosition` return. IG: put your function inside `function(position){}`

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers, including the iPhone browser, support a (draft) [W3C `navigator.geolocation` API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).